# How best to handle accounts across two different systems?

Tags: api, oauth, shopify-api

I want to use Shopify for our commerce solution but to build out a custom admin/user settings system. The key hurdle I'm dealing with is users and authentication. Let's assume my site is a.com and my admin system is my.a.com on a different host. I want the user to be able to log in to both the Shopify site and their custom admin/user page using the same username and password (effectively SSO but without a third-party service).

**Constraints:**

- I don't want to build a custom application as I foresee us ultimately going fully custom at some point down the road
- Just in case someone asks, yes the admin/user settings page is complex/unique enough that it warrants a custom solution to provide a good user experience.

### Possible Solution 1

Have accounts created on the custom admin site and use the Create Customer API to keep the two databases in sync.

Questions:

- How do I handle the email validation coming from Shopify (the customer should be oblivious to Shopify as it's an implementation detail)

### Possible Solution 2

Have all accounts created via Shopify and the admin site and create an associated on on the admin site.

Questions:

- How do I handle authentication for a specific user across origins. The only OAuth scenarios I seem to be able to track down are at the app level not per user.

I greatly appreciate any insights you all may have. Thank you.

Comment: Just find a simple oauth2 server and off you go!

Comment: @Evert I appreciate the response but that doesn't really help outside of implying having a central auth system. If that's the case, any suggestions, tutorials, am I correct in my understanding of your comment?

Comment: The oauth.net website has a good list of services and open source tools: https://oauth.net/code/ all of those are likely good picks.